# Cannot find named PHP session module (memcache)

Tags: php, magento, memcached

I update from Magento 1.6.2 to 1.8.1 and now I get this on my page:

```
    Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (memcache)  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 73
    #0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'session_module_...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 73, Array)
    #1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(73): session_module_name('memcache')
    #2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start('adminhtml')
     #3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', 'adminhtml')
     #4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', 'adminhtml')
    #5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1353): Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
    #6 /app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/session', Array)
    #7 /app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/session', Array)
    #8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(493): Mage::getSingleton('core/session', Array)
    #9 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
    #10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
    #11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #13 /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #14 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #15 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #16 {main}
```

I have checked everything I could find on the net, but can't seem to solve this one?
I don't know what session module it is looking for? PHP? memcache?
I have been locked out for 3 days now!!!

Comment: did you configure magento to use memcache for sessions ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your `app/etc/local.xml` file is configured to use the PHP `memcache` session storage handler.  When Magento reads this configuration value in and tries to set the session handler with the [session_module_name](http://php.net/session_module_name) function it finds the version of PHP you're using doesn't have the `memcache` session hander installed and/or enabled.

You'll need to disable this configuration value in your `app/etc/local.xml` file and use the standard file/database session storage method, or you'll need to install/enable the session handler on the server you've installed Magento on.